# TCP приём данных

Tags: c#, сокет, tcp-ip

Здравствуйте!
Я использую TCP(Socket) для отправки данных, если данных много, больше 4-х гигабайт, то приложение падает с ошибкой - переполнение памяти!

Я полученные байты отправляю в ConcurrentQueue, а отдельный поток обрабатывает эти байты, но данные приходят довольно быстро, что тот поток, который обрабатывает эти байты просто напросто не успевает и количество в ConcurrentQueue растёт и соответственно увеличивается память.

Подскажите пожалуйста, что можно сделать в этой ситуации?

Comment: Для начала просто сравните скорость входного потока с возможной скоростью передачи по TCP.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решение зависит от того, что именно за данные вы передаете.

Допустимо ли просто приостановить передачу данных? Если да, то вам надо попросту выкинуть из схемы очередь и обрабатывать поступающие данные напрямую. Если приемник в такой схеме начнет простаивать - просто увеличивайте размер буфера приема в настройках сокета. Протокол TCP обладает механизмами (т.н. окна приема и передачи), которые автоматически подстроят скорость передачи данных под скорость их обработки.

Если же приостанавливать передачу недопустимо (поток реального времени) - допустимо ли терять часть данных? Если допустимо - то вам пора сменить используемый протокол - UDP подойдет куда лучше. А еще лучше подойдет RTP, позволяющий управлять скоростью передачи - но он куда сложнее.

Наконец, если нельзя ни тормозить передачу, ни выкидывать часть данных - переходим к хранению принятых данных. Самый простой способ - использовать 64-битную архитектуру, ей доступно куда больше памяти. Однако, на больших объемах используемой памяти начинает тормозить уже сборщик мусора, так что простая схема архитектуры может и не помочь. Кроме того, 64 бита не всегда доступны.

Альтернативный метод - можно записывать поступающие данные в файл. На диске места точно хватит. Если же вы не успеваете даже записать данные на диск - то надо уже менять железо. Хотя может помочь сжатие данных (а может и не помочь).

Answer (score 1):

Например можно не принимать новые данные из TCP-соединения пока очередь в ConcurrentQueue больше какого-то порога. Это заставит отправителя отправлять данные медленнее и вы успеете их обработать.

Если это не возможно - складывать данные в какой-то промежуточный буфер на диске и потом вычитывать их оттуда.

Ну и если памяти достаточно и нужно работать именно с полным объемом и в памяти - проверить что используются 64-битные сборки - у 32-битных могут быть проблемы при работе с памятью объемом больше 2-3Гб (например пока данные шли 2Гб обработаться успело, 2 не успело и когда необработанные данные перевалили за 2Гб - наступил каюк потому что 32 бита и больше памяти адресовать не получается).